# Swift / SpriteKit - Path with SKShapeNode is hollow (empty)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to draw a line between two circles. Circles are fine, however lines have outlines themselves, leaving the inside empty. I would like the lines to be solid, and not "outlined lines". Here is the code for drawing the line followed by a screenshot.

```
var line = SKShapeNode()
var path = CGPathCreateMutable()

// touch object stores startPosition and endPosition
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, touch!.startPosition.x, touch!.startPosition.y)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, touch!.endPosition!.x, touch!.endPosition!.y)

line.path = path
line.lineWidth = 10
line.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor() // Not sure if this line is actually needed
line.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.nodeLayer.addChild(line)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlJaj.jpg (Can't post embed images due to reputation)

Comment: From Apple's SKShapeNode documentation "A line width larger than 2.0 may cause rendering artifacts in the final rendered image. The default value is 1.0." Perhaps it would be better to draw a filled rectangle to connect the two circles.

Comment: I've considered this already, and maybe that's the way to go, even though it sounds sloppy. Thanks for the feedback, by the way.

Comment: Have you tried it on an actual device? I've found that sometimes the simulator won't render `SKShapeNode`s correctly, but the actual devices will; especially with Xcode6/iOS8.

Comment: Mike, you are right. I just tested the code within an actual device and it works. However, before testing on a device I've already managed a workaround with a shape. I'll stick to the shape I created because I have more flexibility modify its path.